# Need help with Ruby case statements

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

It seems as if my code never runs through the switch statement. Every time I create a Deck object, every Card object has nil for both the suit and the name. Can anyone help me out?

```
class Card
def initialize (suit, number, name)
    @suit = suit
    @number = number
    @name = name         #
end
attr_reader :suit, :number, :name
end

class Deck
      def initialize
          @deck = Array.new
          for i in 0...4
              suit = case i
                  when i == 0 then "Spades"
                  when i == 1 then "Hearts"
                  when i == 2 then "Diamonds"
                  when i == 3 then "Clubs"
              end
          puts i
          puts suit     #Debug only
          for j in 2...15
              name = case j
                  when j == 2 then "Two of #{suit}"
                  when j == 3 then "Three of #{suit}"
                  when j == 4 then "Four of #{suit}"
                  when j == 5 then "Five of #{suit}"
                  when j == 6 then "Six of #{suit}"
                  when j == 7 then "Seven of #{suit}"
                  when j == 8 then "Eight of #{suit}"
                  when j == 9 then "Nine of #{suit}"
                  when j == 10 then "Ten of #{suit}"
                  when j == 11 then "Jack of #{suit}"
                  when j == 12 then "Queen of #{suit}"
                  when j == 13 then "King of #{suit}"
                  when j == 14 then "Ace of #{suit}"
              end
              puts j
              puts name   #Debug only
              @deck.push(Card.new(suit, j, name))
          end
      end
  end
  attr_reader :deck    
end
```

Comment: Less repetition: `suit = %w[Spades Hearts Diamonds Clubs][i]; name = %w[Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Jack Queen King Ace][j-2] + " of #{suit}"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `case` statement implicitly applies the `===` operator. So you want something more like:

```
case j
when 2 then "Two of #{suit}"
when 3 then "Three of #{suit}"
# ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Your case statement shouldnt contain the actual boolean comparisons, but instead should be the literals, like:

```
case j
when 2
 "Two of #{suit}"
when 3
 "Three of #{suit}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was awesome too.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use `case` for this to begin with. You don't even need Hashes, a couple Arrays would do fine:

```
suits = %w{Spades Hearts Diamonds Clubs}
values = %w{- - Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Jack Queen King Ace}
deck = suits.map do |s|
  (2..14).map do |i|
    Card.new(s,i,"#{values[i]} of #{s}")
  end
end.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy and Cody already answered correct. Just another view:

Your when-clause test for i == 0. This comparison returns true or false.
So, when you test for true, your code could work:

```
[0,1,2,3 ].each{|i|
  print "Test #{i}. Hit: "
  case true
      when i == 0 then puts  "Spades"
      when i == 1 then puts "Hearts"
      when i == 2 then puts "Diamonds"
      when i == 3 then puts "Clubs"
    end
}
```

Please don't use code like this. It may work, but it's nonsense. Use the code Jeremy and Cody  already posted:

```
[0,1,2,3 ].each{|i|
  print "Test #{i}. Hit: "
  case i
      when 0 then puts  "Spades"
      when 1 then puts "Hearts"
      when 2 then puts "Diamonds"
      when 3 then puts "Clubs"
    end
}
```